# Are options on the derivatives exchange suspended when the underlying stock is suspended?

Tags: stocks, options

Suppose a stock is suspended on the stock exchange (e.g. NYSE). What will happen to the options on the derivatives exchange (e.g. CBOE)? Will the options be suspended too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Options exchanges usually suspend when the "Primary Exchange" suspends trading.  There may be some exceptions for certain order types and certain types of  suspension (e.g. limit-up-limit-down).  The exchange's rules would provide the specifics.  In CBOE's case, it is up to an exchange official to halt trading, but they would consider if trading of the underlying has been halted on another exchange. (CBOE Rule 5.20).

Some may allow trading to continue if the primary exchange is halted due to technical problems (e.g. it is trading elsewhere, e.g. on Arca and NASDAQ)

Furthermore, the exchange's market makers who provide continuous quotes may suspend quoting if they are unable to find a firm price for the underlying security, or there is insufficient liquidity.  Their lack of presence isn't sufficient to halt trading but it would make the spreads wider and therefore less economic to trade the securities in question.

Answer (score 0):

It will be up to the exchange - you can look at the exchange regulations on the exchange website. But I suspect not.